# Warning</b>: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in getting this error on parsing &,>,<, i.e htmlspecialchars to php script.How to avoid it?

Tags: php, html, json

I am trying to parse some data in handson table to the server side .I am passing it row by row in JSON format and decoding it as an array on server side. It works fine when row doesn't have any html specialchars but gives the above error when some '&' ,'>','<' character is present and data is not updated for that row.Here is my server side code. I have the data from handsontable's row in $all_data variable.
As i have PHP 5.1.6 , i am using PEAR extension for Json encode/decode.

Here is my php code:

```
<?php include("/lan/fed/etpv/cgi-bin/testplans/php/my_functions.php"); ?>
<?php
$dbh=mysql_connect('a','b','c');
if(! $dbh ) {
          die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$json = new Services_JSON(SERVICES_JSON_LOOSE_TYPE); // to json decode from string to array
$database=mysql_select_db('testmohit');
$data_size = (int) $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'];
$testplan_name=$_POST['testplan_name'];
$product=$_POST['product'];
$release=$_POST['release'];
$pv_engg=$_POST['pv_engg'];
$pe_engg=$_POST['pe_engg'];
$rd_engg=$_POST['rd_engg'];
$tp_completion=$_POST['tp_completion'];
$at_completion=$_POST['at_completion'];
$logged_user=$_POST['logged_user'];
$plan_creator=$_POST['plan_creator'];
$headers=stripslashes($_POST['headers']);
$all_data = stripslashes($_POST['all_data']); //# to remove \ before " that occur when parsed through ajax
print"$all_data";
$all_data=htmlspecialchars($all_data);
//print "$data_size";
$headers=$json->decode($headers);
$all_data=$json->decode($all_data);
for($j=0;$j<count($headers);$j++) {
      $headers[$j]= str_replace(' ','_',strtolower("$headers[$j]"));
}
$date=date('Y-m-d');
//print_r($all_data);
$result = array();
foreach($all_data as $key => $val){ //this is done to convert the simple array to associative array with headers as keys and all_data values as values.
    $temp = array();
    foreach($val as $k => $v){
       $temp[$headers[$k]] = $v;
    }
    $fields=get_other_fields("$temp[testcase_path]");
    if($temp[$headers[1]] == '') {
    $temp[$headers[1]] = $fields['Top_module_name'];
    }
    if($temp[$headers[2]] == '') {
    $temp[$headers[2]] = $fields['Customer_Name'];
    }
    if($temp[$headers[3]] == '') {
    $temp[$headers[3]] = $fields['Flops'];
    }
    $result[] = $temp;
}  //after this all the data is converted in the required form

          $query = "UPDATE testplans SET percent_tpcompletion='$tp_completion',percent_atcompletion='$at_completion',tc_name='$temp[testcase_name]',cell_name='$temp[cell_name]',customer_name='$temp[customer]',flops='$temp[flops]',title='$temp[title]',status='$temp[status]',mfix_ccr='$temp[mfix_ccr]',test_scenerio='$temp[scenerio_brief_description]',expected_results='$temp[expected_results]',ccr_no='$temp[ccr_no]',ccr_status='$temp[status]',remarks='$temp[remarks]',edit_date='$date',edit_by='$logged_user' WHERE id='$temp[id]'";
         # print "$query";
         mysql_select_db('testmohit');
          $enter=mysql_query($query,$dbh);
          if(! $enter) {
           die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
          }
```

So what i am saying is that when the data in a row($all_data) do not have htmlspecialchars() query is successful.Else it gives the above error.
How to rectify it .Please suggest something.I tried using htmlspecialchars() function but , it didn't helped.

Thanks

Comment: please fix the code formatting so we can read it

Comment: `$all_data` is most likely a string and not array. What makes you think its an array? At least it becomes a string when passed to `htmlspecialchars()` and `stripslashes()`. Also, `htmlspecialchars()` should be used on *output*, never input. It will mangle your data, making it harder to work with.

Comment: The `mysql_` library is deprecated, and removed entirely in newer versions of PHP - so you should not use it in new code! Learn the MySQLi or PDO interfaces instead, and learn how to use parameterized queries with placeholders.

Comment: its is also not working without htmlspecialchars().It doesn't make any difference.Do you have a solution for the current scenerio as i have older version of php 5.1.6

Comment: if you add a `var_dump($all_data);` before the foreach, you can know what type of value is in the variable and decide how to fix your code properly

Comment: @confused Because most likely, `$_POST['all_data'}` is a *string* and not an array. But like I said, you shouldn't use any of those functions on input to the database.

Comment: @Qirel > no, it's most likely an object (coming from $json->decode() a few lines above the foreach). Anyway OP needs to learn to debug and see for him(her)self.

Comment: var_dump is displaying null followed by the same error in the failed scenerio @calimero

Comment: Ahh, I didn't see that decoding. Which doesn't make much sense, when the variable passed into `json_decode()` is a stripped and escaped string coming from `$_POST['all_data']`. I'd dump the `$_POST['all_data']` instead of dumping the variable, so we know what sort of input we're dealing with though - it's being treated as a string, then `json_decode()`'ed, I'm confused about the end result here.

Comment: @confused you don't say in the question but there is a `print` of the variable above, does that display some json at all ? If yes, try to remove the `htmlspecialchars()` and see if that helps.

Comment: no it doesn't changes anything.

Comment: then also replace `$all_data = stripslashes($_POST['all_data']);` by `$all_data = $_POST['all_data'];`

Comment: practically remove everything happening to the value until json-decoding it, to allow it to work. You'll fix any subsequent problem later.

Comment: Better look at the input directly, start from there. `var_dump($_POST['all_data']);` - is it a string? An array? Anything that can be json-decoded? Treat your input from what it is, don't expect it can be decoded if you don't know what's coming in (and specially if you escape it). Those functions (`htmlspecialchars()`) shouldn't be there in the first place, as you're sending input from a form to a database. Same thing with stripslashes, it's the wrong application for those functions. You should instead insert the variables with a prepared statement.

Comment: "[["PIPE7_parallel","","","0","","Done","","Validate parallel TDL vectors for 2D Elastic ","No miscompares for both scan and logic tests ","Done",null,"Lets Check\ngpreeti:testing","/lan/fed/etpv/release/171/lnx86/etautotest/flow/2D_PIPELINES/PIPE7_parallel","159"]]" This is my $all_data after stripslashes and yes it can be json decoded , it causes problem only in the case of & etc as i have mentioned before.

Comment: I have figured out where i am missing.But i don't know how to rectify it.When & is present in the data entered by user it takes it as the variable separator of datastring .My data string is  var datastring = 'testplan_name='+testplan_name+'&product='+product+'&release='+release+'&pv_engg='+pv_engg+'&pe_engg='+pe_engg+'&r
d_engg='+rd_engg+'&tp_completion='+tp_completion+'&at_completion='+at_completion+'&headers='+all_headers+'&all_data='+all_data+'&logged
_user='+logged_user+'&plan_creator='+plan_creator; so when & is present in all_data its value remains till & and JSON format is broken .

Comment: Due to broken JSON,i.e , ]" not present, it can't be JSON decoded properly and , i get this error, how can i fix this on frontend so that while sending & in data it is not treated as a variable separator.